# filter clean leaves uncommitted file

Tags: git

I'm cross posting this from the git mailing list (http://marc.info/?l=git&m=139287161008313&w=2)

So, I want a way of sharing parts of a gitconfig organizationally, so
I change and comment out some parts with a filter:

[filter "gitconfig-rmuser"]
  clean = sed -e \"s/^\( *email =\).*/\1 /\" -e
\"s/^\( *name =\).*/\1 /\" -e \"s/^\( *signingkey

=\).*/\1 /\"

And then:
$ cat .gitattributes
* filter=ident-line
gitconfig filter=gitconfig-rmuser

Which works. The only problem is that if I change it again after the
commit, I get:
$ git status
# HEAD detached at e872204
# Changes not staged for commit:
#       modified:   gitconfig
#
no changes added to commit
$ git diff gitconfig
$

So the repo remains dirty and I can't do anything with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you modify a filtered file, it looks to be dirty to git. When git stages files to the index, it stores the checksum of the actual file rather than the checksum of the filtered file. So after modifying your file, you need to `git add` it. This will modify the index, but (if your modification is invisible with regard to the filter) not cause a change to be commited later.

Comment: Thanks - I never thought of 'adding' a file already being tracked.